# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function listarUsuarios()

Tags: php

Estou iniciando no PHP e estou sofrendo com um problema ao utilizar o paradigma de [dal](/questions/tagged/dal).
O que pretendo fazer é apenas um `SELECT` de todos os usuários cadastrados no banco mysql e retornar a uma pagina, estou utilizando a seguinte lógica:

**listar-usuarios.php**

```
<?php
 require_once 'cabecalho.php';
 require_once 'conectadb.php';
require_once 'Usuario.php';
require_once 'UsuarioDAO.php';
?>
<!-- Listando os Usuarios-->
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome:</th>
            <th>E-mail:</th>
            <th>Estado:</th>
            <th>Cidade:</th>
            <th>Status:</th>
            <th>Permissao:</th>
            <th>Data do cadastro:</th>
            <th>Opções</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <?php
            $usuarios = listarUsuarios();
            foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) :
                ?>
                <td><?= $usuario->getNome() ?></td>
                <td><?= $usuario->getEmail() ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        endforeach
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UsuarioDAO.php**

```
require_once 'conectadb.php';
require_once 'Usuario.php';

 class UsuarioDAO {

 private $conexao;

  function __construct($conexao) {
    $this->conexao = $conexao;
  }
  public function listarUsuarios(){
    $usuarios = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuario");
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->setIdusuario($array['idusuario']);
        $usuario->setNome($array['nome']);
        $usuario->setEmail($array['email']);
        $usuario->setEstado($array['estado']);
        $usuario->setCidade($array['cidade']);
        $usuario->setStatus($array['status']);
        $usuario->setPermissao($array['permissao']);
        $usuario->setDatacadastro($array['datacadastro']);
        array_push($usuarios, $usuario);
    }
    return $usuarios;
   }
 }
```

**Usuario.php**

```
 <?php

class Usuario{

private $idusuario;
private $nome;
private $email;
private $cep;
private $estado;
private $cidade;
private $bairro;
private $telefone;
private $status;
private $permissao;
private $datacadastro;
private $ipcadastro;
private $senha;

 Getter and setters

  ...Codigo omitido...
```

O erro apresentado pelo PHP é:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `listarUsuarios()` in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin-ame\listar-usuarios.php:47 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin-ame\listar-usuarios.php on line 47

Essa falha pode estar ocorrendo porque não chamei a classe `DAO` no arquivo `Listar-Usuarios.php?`

Comment: Voce usou o $usuarios = new UsuarioDAO; acho que pode ser isso

Comment: Faltou instanciar o objeto `UsuarioDAO` como o @MatheusLopesMarques disse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boas,

Estas a chamar uma função que está dentro do objeto "**UsuarioDAO**". tens de iniciar uma nova instância.

```
$usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO($conexao);
$usuarios = $usuarioDAO->listarUsuarios();
```

também precisas de definir a variavel **$conexao** que penso estar ligado com alguma coisa no ficheiro **conectadb.php**